# Ubuntu 15.04 randomly freezes

Tags: dell

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 (64 bit) on a DELL XPS 13 (model 9343, 2015 edition - bios A03). It is a dual boot machine (Windows and Linux). I am having an annoying problem: Ubuntu randomly freezes. The screen does NOT go blank, mouse and keyboard do not work, touchpad does not work. I ran the bios diagnostic tests and found no hardware problems. My kernel is 3.19.0-16.

Comment: See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze - The fact of the matter is that without additional information it is impossible for us to support you. We need to know your hardware and any errors in the logs. FWIW most, if not all of the freezes I have seen come from one or several of the following -  (bad hardware ) faulty graphics drivers, faulty wireless drivers, kernel bugs, bad RAM, and/or bad hard drive.

Comment: If you have a kernel bug, the first thing you will be asked is if the problem persists on the most recent stable kernel release (from kernel.org), which is a bit of a hassle to say the least. Closest is the ubuntu mainline kernel - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Comment: The crashes are happening when I suspend to RAM. Sometimes when I try to suspend to RAM the computer freezes and the Caps Lock light keeps blinking. I am attaching form info on my hardware.

Comment: <code>cribari@darwin4:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
A03
cribari@darwin4:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date
03/25/2015
cribari@darwin4:~$ sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name
0310JH
cribari@darwin4:~$ sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer</code>

Comment: [code]cribari@darwin4:~$ uname -a
Linux darwin4 3.19.0-16-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 30 16:09:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
cribari@darwin4:~$ apt-cache policy bcmwl-kernel-source
bcmwl-kernel-source:
  Installed: 6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/restricted amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status[/code]

Comment: [code]cribari@darwin4:~$ lsb_release -rd
Description: Ubuntu 15.04
Release: 15.04[/code]

Comment: I am having the same problem but I could not find the symptoms under the ubuntu wiki.  I'm just bothered that I keep forcely restarting the machine and will be having an HDD failure anytime soon.